# Why does Date accept negative values?

Tags: javascript

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

*"Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC."*

Then why does it accept negative values ?

Even if it did shouldn't negative value mean values before Jan 1, 1970 ?

```
new Date('0000', '00', '-1');   // "1899-12-30T05:00:00.000Z"
new Date('0000', '00', '00');   // "1899-12-31T05:00:00.000Z"
new Date('-9999', '99', '99');  // "-009991-07-08T04:00:00.000Z"
```

What is happening ?

**Update**

For some positive values , the year begins from 1900

```
new Date(100);                  // "1970-01-01T00:00:00.100Z"   // it says 100Z
new Date(0100);                 // "1970-01-01T00:00:00.064Z"   // it says 64Z
new Date("0006","06","06");     // "1906-07-06T04:00:00.000Z"
```

Also note that, in the last one, the date is shown as 4 which is wrong.

I suspect this is some sort of Y2K bug ?!!

Comment: @mplungjan note the word *since*

Comment: Note that new Date(0) is 1970 (with relevant TZ)

Comment: @mplungjan does this mean there is a way to represent a time in BC ?

Comment: @FlyingGambit Gregorian calendar can be "reverse extended" to BC dates, but it will cease to be historically accurate long before that.  Jesus did not invent the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: @TrojanByAccident, this is the number of milliseconds that is calculated _since_ the epoch. Here the term _since_ give a direction in time. So positive will be after, negative will be before. (this is how I understand it)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> This is hard and inconsistent, yes. The JavaScript Date object was [based on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#JavaScript_and_Java) the one in Java 1.0, which is [so bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api) that Java [redesigned](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) a whole new package.
>   JavaScript is not so lucky.

1. Date is "based on" [unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) because of how it is [defined](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-objects). It's *internal* details.
2. `1st Jan 1970` is the actual time of this baseline.
3. `since` is the direction of the timestamp value: forward for +ve, backward for -ve.
4. *Externally*, the Date constructor has several different usages, based on parameters:

## Zero parameters = current time

```
new Date()   // Current datetime. Every tutorial should teach this.
```

> The time is absolute, but 'displayed' timezone may be UTC or local.
>
> For simplicity, this answer will use only UTC.  **Keep timezone in mind when you test.**

## One *numeric* parameter = timestamp @ 1970

```
new Date(0)    // 0ms from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
new Date(100)  // 100ms from 1970 baseline.
new Date(-10)  // -10ms from 1970 baseline.
```

## One *string* parameter = [iso date string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

```
new Date('000')        // Short years are invalid, need at least four digits.
new Date('0000')       // 0000-01-01.  Valid because there are four digits.
new Date('1900')       // 1900-01-01.
new Date('1900-01-01') // Same as above.
new Date('1900-01-01T00:00:00') // Same as above.
new Date('-000001')    // 2 BC, see below. Yes you need all those zeros.
```

## Two or more parameters = year, month, and so on @ 1900 or 0000

```
new Date(0,0)      // 1900-01-01T00:00:00Z.
new Date(0,0,1)    // Same as above.  Date is 1 based.
new Date(0,0,0)    // 1 day before 1900 = 1899-12-31.
new Date(0,-1)     // 1 month before 1900 = 1899-12-01.
new Date(0,-1,0)   // 1 month and 1 day before 1900 = 1899-11-30.
new Date(0,-1,-1)  // 1 month and *2* days before 1900 = 1899-11-29.
new Date('0','1')  // 1900-02-01. Two+ params always cast to year and month.
new Date(100,0)    // 0100-01-01. Year > 99 use year 0 not 1900.
new Date(1900,0)   // 1900-01-01. Same as new Date(0,0). So intuitive!
```

## Negative year = BC

```
new Date(-1,0)    // 1 year before 0000-01-01 = 1 year before 1 BC = 2 BC.
new Date(-1,0,-1) // 2 days before 2 BC.  Fun, yes?  I'll leave this as an exercise.
```

> There is no 0 AC.  There is 1 AC and the year before it is 1 BC.  [Year 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years) is 1 BC by convention.
>
> 2 BC is displayed as year `"-000001"`.
>   The extra zeros are [required](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years) because it is outside normal range (0000 to 9999).
>   If you `new Date(12345,0)` you will get `"+012345-01-01"`, too.
>
> Of course, the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), adopted as late as 1923 in Europe, will cease to be meaningful long before we reach BC.
>   In fact, scholars [accept that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_of_birth_of_Jesus_of_Nazareth) Jesus wasn't born in 1 BC.
>   But with [the stars](http://spaceplace.nasa.gov/starfinder2/en/) and [the land](http://www.iflscience.com/environment/australia-suddenly-move-north-new-years-day/) moving at this scale, calendar is the least of your worries.

---

The remaining given code are just variations of these cases. For example:

```
new Date(0100)          // One number = epoch. 0100 (octal) = 64ms since 1970
new Date('0100')        // One string = iso = 0100-01-01.
new Date(-9999, 99, 99) // 9999 years before BC 1 and then add 99 months and 98 days
```

Hope you had some fun time.  Please don't forget to vote up. :)

> To stay sane, keep all dates in ISO 8601 and use the string constructor. 
>   And if you need to handle timezone, keep all datetimes in UTC.

Comment: Just a question - why does `new Date('00000100')` report the same as `new Date(0100)`?

Comment: @TrojanByAccident I tested in Firefox 50 and Edge 38, both reports "Invalid Date" for `new Date("00000100")`, so don't do that. Chrome 55 parse it as `new Date("0100")` *not* `new Date(0100)` (type matters).

Comment: Interesting. Testing in Chrome 55, `new Date('00000100')` reports as *Fri Jan 01 100*, and `new Date(00000100)` reports as *Wed Dec 31 1969*

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly, you're passing in string instead of an integer, so that might have something to do with your issues here.

Check [this out](http://scholarslab.org/research-and-development/parsing-bc-dates-with-javascript), it explains negative dates quite nicely, and there is an explanation for your exact example.

Comment: I am unable to open that link due to web security issues, however , can you explain it in brief so that even if the link breaks in future, we still have some concrete answer

Comment: I really don't think we're allowed to just copy paste someone elses blog post on the topic

Comment: You could always quote it. I say this because I can't open that link either (just infinite loading icon)

Comment: @darryn.ten you can sumarise the ideas or copy small pieces that are relevant. As long as you link to the source it is usually considered OK. As it stands your post could be flagged as a link only answer

Comment: @darryn.ten That explains how `new Date('-9999', '99', '99');  // "-009991-07-08T04:00:00.000Z"` works but not the rest, especially `new Date('0000', '00', '00');   // "1899-12-31T05:00:00.000Z"`

Comment: Year: Values from 0 to 99 map to the years 1900 to 1999

Comment: @FlyingGambit new Date('0000', '00', '00') is invalid. How can you have a 0 month and 0 day?

Comment: @KScandrett Just testing, sometimes curiosity overtakes me

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> Year: Values from 0 to 99 map to the years 1900 to 1999

1. 1970 with appropriate timezone: new Date(0); // int MS since 1970
2. 1900 (or 1899 with applied timezone): new Date(0,0) or new Date(0,0,1) - date is 1 based, month and year are 0 based
3. 1899: new Date(0,0,-1)

Answer (score 0):

> Then why does it accept negative values ?

You are confusing the description of how the data is stored internally with the arguments that the constructor function takes.

> Even if it did shouldn't negative value mean values before Jan 1, 1970 ?

No, for the above reason. Nothing stops the [year, month or day from being negative](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.12). You just end up adding a negative number to something.

> Also note that, in the last one, the date is shown as 4 which is wrong.

Numbers which [start with a `0` are expressed in octal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Integers), not decimal. `0100 === 64`.